# How to Dynamically Load in React Images

Tags: reactjs, image

I'm trying to include an image in my react project for some reason when I include the static path it works but when I dynamically load it in, it gives me a:

> Cannot find module error

I'm using require to load in the image per another SO post.

```
{tokenslist.map((a, index) => {
    <div rowSpan="2" style={{verticalAlign: 'middle'}}><img src={require(a.logo)} className="doggericon" /></div>
})
```

Comment: what is `a.logo`? when its an url then you dont need `require`

Comment: @Sysix a.logo is the path

Comment: what u expect as an output? the img src is an url/pfad. do you try to convert it to base64?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the logo returns just the file name or full path, but if its full path you can do something like here:

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const tokenlist = [
    {
      logo: "https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200",
      name: "Image 1"
    },
    {
      logo: "https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/200",
      name: "Image 2"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {tokenlist &&
        tokenlist.map((a, index) => (
          <div>
            <img src={a.logo} alt={a.name} />
            {a.name}
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here, `tokenlist` is just the dummy data list. If the image is not the full path and just the file name, you have to add the path and concatenate the file name, at last, something like `src={`${process.env.APP_URL}/public/uploads//${a.logo}`}`

- Here `process.env.APP_URL` returns the app URL, if you are not using `.env`, you can replace it with your `APP_URL` something like `http://example.com`. Although it's best practice to store `APP_URL` in a single place.
- Next, `public/uploads` are just the sample path, you might need to replace it according to your app storage locations.

Here, is the working sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-brook-nwopfz?file=/src/App.js:0-478